# C# - How to get PropertyInfo of anonymous object in List

Tags: c#, arraylist, anonymous-types

I am writing Blazor component for table which can use all objects and via reflection access their properties.

My issue is in sorting function via LINQ. I have class `Column` which has property `bool Sortable`. If sortable is true then sort button appears. On clicking that button I know which property name to sort by. However the list object is dynamic. So to use LINQ `OrderBy` function I need to get `PropertyInfo` first.

If I would have only object not list of object then I would do

```
object.GetType().GetProperty(mySortFieldViaParameter)
```

I dont know how to get properly that `PropertyInfo` from `List` via

```
list.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single().GetProperty(mySortFieldViaParameter)
```

returns null. Null because `list.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single()` returns `System.Object` not Anonymous type like `list[0]`.

One idea how to get this working is adding condition "if list.count > 0 then get `list[0].GetType().GetProperty(...)`". However is it even possible to do what I just described without that condition?

LINQ function looks like then:

```
list.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList()
```

Comment: Have you considered calling `GetType` (etc.) on the first item in the list?  Something like: `list.FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().GetProperty(mySortFieldViaParameter)`

Comment: Yea that's what I mentioned at post.. considering to add condition if list.count > 0 because cant get type of null right

Comment: I can not reproduce you problem, for me it works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1jneyg

Comment: Where is your list declared?  What type is it?  My guess, since you don't know what types are in it (and because that's what Reflection is telling you), is that it is a `List<object>`.  If it were me, I'd be using null-conditional operators (`.?`) and then, if the result is null, I'd figure that there's nothing to sort and call it "not sortable"

Comment: @thehennyy https://dotnetfiddle.net/DbdmyK

Comment: If it's a `List<dynamic>`, it's the same as a `List<object>` under the covers (with dynamic taint added by the compiler).  So, yeah, you can't get type of what's being collected from the list's type.  Such is life.

Comment: @Flydog57 declared outside component. Its List<dynamic>

Comment: @Flydog57 well then its like i thought. Not solvable without condition